# create dynamic datatable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to create the datatable `thead` time accordingly, but I am having trouble when saving the day shift, changing from `AM-PM OR PM-AM`.
I want when the condition is `D` it means it's the day shift and the `thead` should start from `9AM-9PM`; when the condition is `N` it means it's night shift and the `thead` should start from `9PM-9AM`.

```
<table class="table" id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr></tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

```
 function load_table(status) {
   $("table#mytable thead tr").empty();
   let initTime = 0 - 3;
   let startTime = 9;
   if (status == "D") {
     for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
       $("table#mytable thead tr").append(`
        <th>${startTime} - ${startTime+1 <= 12 ? startTime+1 +"AM"  : initTime+"PM"} </th>
       `);
       startTime++, initTime++;
     }
   } else {
     for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
       $("table#mytable thead tr").append(`
       <th>${startTime} - ${startTime+1 <= 12 ? startTime+1 +"PM"  : initTime+"AM"} </th>
       `);
       startTime++;
     }
   }
 }
 load_table("N");
 // D =  DAY & N = Night
 // Day = 9AM - 9PM
 // Night = 9PM - 9AM
```

Comment: Why not change where the loops start depending on whether `status` is "D" or "N"? `startTime` is always 9, so start the night shift with `i = 12`. You'll need to add code that resets `startTime` to 0 at midnight. I'm not sure what `initTime` is supposed to be, starting at -3...

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem will be made much easier if you separate the logic of formatting the shifts from the code that constructs the HTML. One advantage of this is that it will make testing the shift construction (the hard part) easier because it will return an array that we can view in the console.

I would also initially create each hour according to the 24-hour clock in order to make the AM/PM logic easy. I would convert the hour to the 12-hour clock only when formatting it for presentation. We can put the formatting logic into its own function.

The code becomes:

```js
const formatHour = hour => {
  const suffix = (hour % 24) >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  const formattedHour = hour % 12 || 12;
  
  return `${formattedHour}${suffix}`;
}
 
const getHours = status => {
  const startHour = status === 'D' ? 9 : 21;

  return (new Array(12)).fill(0).map((_, i) => {
    const start = (startHour + i) % 24;
    const end = (start + 1);
      
    return `${formatHour(start)} - ${formatHour(end)}`;
  });
}

const mapHoursToHtml = hours => hours.map(hour => {
  return `<th>${hour}</th>`;
}).join('');

$("#mytableD thead tr").append(mapHoursToHtml(getHours('D')));
$("#mytableN thead tr").append(mapHoursToHtml(getHours('N')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="mytableD">
  <thead>
    <tr></tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<table class="table" id="mytableN">
  <thead>
    <tr></tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```